# Making a D&D game running into issues

Tags: python, typeerror, user-input

I have been learning Python for a while and I  decided to make a D&D type game on my own.
I am trying to make a user input to choose out of 3 characters each with their own hit point etc...
When the Users character encounter a monster and gets attacked by the monster I want to subtract hit points from the user character. I am just a beginner and not sure how to solve this problem, here is my code for a example....

```
 Choose_Character = input('Choose a character:\n1.Warrior\n2.Wizard\n3.Elf\n')

if Choose_Character == '1':
  Warrior = {'HP':140,'Magic':23}
  print('Here are you character stats:\nHit Points: ' + str(Warrior['HP'])+ 'nMagic Points: ' + str(Warrior['Magic']))




if Choose_Character == '2':
  Wizard = {'HP':123,'Magic':12}
  print('Here are your character stats:\nHit Points: ' + str(Wizard['HP'])+ '\nMagic Points: ' + str(Wizard['Magic']))


if Choose_Character == '3':
  Elf = {'HP':123,'Magic':12}
  print('Here are your character stats:\nHit Points: ' + str(Elf['HP'])+ '\nMagic Points: ' + str(Elf['Magic']))

  

    
fox = {'HP':123,'Magic':12}

print('You encounter a fox he bites you. you lode 20 Hit Points')

new_stats = int(Choose_Character['HP'] - 20)
print(f'your Hit Points are now:{new_stats}')
```

I get a error: TypeError: string indices must be integers
I want to be able to take the user input character and at any point in the game use that input to add or subtract points from the character dictionary.

Comment: Post the full traceback, it will say what line the issue is on.

Comment: `Choose_Character` is a string. What should `Choose_Character["HP"]` mean?

Comment: The problem is OP thinks they are retrieving value from a dictionary with a key. Although `Choose_Character` is not a dictionary, it is a string value... You also should use snake case for variable names.

Comment: You have to change your input into an int, so you then can compare the input values to other integers. When you type your number, it is entered as a string. 
```Choose_Character = int(input('Choose a character:\n1.Warrior\n2.Wizard\n3.Elf\n'))``` You can cast the input as an int, which will then allow you to use it in your if statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into issues because you are trying to access the `'HP'th` index of your input string. Python doesn't understand this command because it doesn't make sense.

An alternative to consider:

```
Choose_Character = input('Choose a character:\n1.Warrior\n2.Wizard\n3.Elf\n')

if Choose_Character == '1':
    character = {'Class': 'Warrior', 'HP': 140, 'Magic': 23}
elif Choose_Character == '2':
    character = {'Class': 'Wizard', 'HP': 123, 'Magic': 12}
elif Choose_Character == '3':
    character = {'Class': 'Elf', 'HP': 123, 'Magic': 12}

print('Here are your character stats:\nHit Points: ' + str(character['HP']) + '\nMagic Points: ' + str(character['Magic']))

fox = {'HP': 123, 'Magic': 12}

print('You encounter a fox he bites you. you lode 20 Hit Points')

new_stats = int(character['HP'] - 20)
print(f'your Hit Points are now:{new_stats}')
```

As an additional suggestion, I would recommend putting your characters, monsters, and items into a class system (as in the programming 'class' and not the RPG 'class'). This will allow you to create copies of them, which allows you to fight the same type of monster more than once without manually resetting a bunch of stuff. It also allows you to implement interesting behavior for monsters. For instance, you could have a class function `on_die` that could specify custom behavior when a monster's HP reaches zero. For slimes, this function could be used to spawn more slimes.
In summary, switching to a class structure would benefit your project a lot.

Comment: Thanks for  the response. I am new to Python and don't have much knowledge on Classes and I was wanting to avoid Classes.Do you suggest I just deep dive into classes to avoid any issues for my game?

Comment: It depends on what your goals are - if your main goal is to make a in-depth RPG then you would probably want to use classes. However, if you are just learning python, you shouldn't feel pressured to use them. It would be a great learning opportunity to use them, though. As a pre-requisite, should understand functions before you try to learn about classes.

Answer (score 0):

Choose_Character is either '1','2' or '3' - which is string thus you get the error you report. As you are trying to access string with ['HP'] but string can be only addressed by integers.

What you actually want to do is something like this

```
  Choose_Character = input('Choose a character:\n1.Warrior\n2.Wizard\n3.Elf\n')

  if Choose_Character == '1':
      hero = {'HP':140,'Magic':23,'Class':'Warrior'} # CHANGED HERE - moved name of class into dict

  if Choose_Character == '2':
      hero = {'HP':123,'Magic':12,'Class':'Wizard'} # CHANGED HERE - moved name of class into dict

  if Choose_Character == '3':
      hero = {'HP':123,'Magic':12,'Class':'Elf'} # CHANGED HERE - moved name of class into dict

  print(f"Here are your {hero['Class']} stats:\nHit Points: {str(hero['HP'])} \nMagic Points: {str(hero['Magic'])}")

  monster = {'HP':123,'Magic':12, 'Name': 'Fox'}

  print(f"You encounter a {monster['Name']} he bites you. you lose 20 Hit Points")

  hero['HP'] = hero['HP'] - 20
  print(f"your Hit Points are now:{hero['HP']}")
```

Or something along this lines... don't give up :D

Comment: Thank you I will try that!