# How do I use a while loop for a game

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
    import random

hero = {'HP':123,'AP':12,'Class':'Wizard'}
monster4 = {'HP':123,'AP':12, 'Name': 'Zantar:Dragon'}

diceRoll = 6

hero_attack = random.randint(1,10)


if hero_attack > diceRoll:
    while hero['HP']>0 and monster4['HP']>0:
        print(f'''You slash at the Dragon cutting off one of his arms. The Dragon has {monster4['HP']-12} hit points left''')
    if hero_attack < diceRoll:
         print(f'''The Dragon claws at you and hurst you badly,you now have {hero['HP']-40} hit points.''')
```

I am trying to finish up my game and this is the final battle between the hero and the dragon. Wondering what the best way to code this. I want to have to have the game end depending on who ever get to zero hit pints first...Should I use a while loop if so I tried and couldn't figure it out..here is a previous question so those new to my question will have some sort of context.
[Making a D&D game running into issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68594260/making-a-dd-game-running-into-issues)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, and we don't deal in designing programs or "the best way to code this" (at least not without an objective standard). We deal in specific problems like "I tried to write this code and X happened, but Y was supposed to happen, [and](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) I took these steps to try to figure out the problem, but I'm stuck because Z".

Comment: my bad I am new to all this,thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

Written with some logical additions.

```
import random

hero = {'HP':123,'AP':12,'Class':'Wizard'}
monster4 = {'HP':123,'AP':40, 'Name': 'Zantar:Dragon'}

diceRoll = 6

# if 1 the game still in progress. if 0 it ended
gameStatus = 1 # will check game status. For while loop


while gameStatus:
    hero_attack = random.randint(1,10) # inside loop, because it makes more sense to get a new value each time.
    
    if hero_attack > diceRoll:
        monster4['HP'] = monster4['HP']-hero['AP'] and monster4['HP']-hero['AP'] or 0  # Attack dmage ['AP'] from source            
        print(f'''You slash at the Dragon cutting off one of his arms. The Dragon has {monster4['HP']} hit points left''')
        print(monster4["HP"])

    if hero_attack < diceRoll:
        hero['HP'] = hero['HP']-monster4['AP'] and hero['HP']-monster4['AP'] or 0 # Attack dmage ['AP'] from source
        print(f'''The Dragon claws at you and hurst you badly,you now have {hero['HP']} hit points.''')
         
         
    gameStatus = (monster4['HP']>0 and hero['HP']>0) and 1 or 0
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try that and see how it goes.